# Error while opening the generated PDF file with Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, outputstream

By using the following code a PDF file is getting opened, I simply write the file to the servlet's output stream, but, when i am trying to open that PDF file it showing an error : "Not a pdf or Corrupted"

My code:

```
public void displayPj() {

    String url = ficheToDisplay.getUrl();
    String outPutFile = ficheToDisplay.getNom();

    HttpServletResponse resp = null;

    resp = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getResponse();
    File file = new File(url);
    resp.reset();
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + outPutFile + "\"");
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        ServletOutputStream outStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream(),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("PROBLEM STREAMING DAILY REPORT PDF THROUGH RESPONSE!"
                        + e);
        e.printStackTrace();

        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Could Not Retrieve PDF.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                "dailyReportArchiveFailure", fm);
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected what actually arrives at the client side? That been asked, are you sure `ficheToDisplay.getUrl()` returns something `new File(url)` can deal with? It sounds more like an URL than like a file path...

Comment: @mkl I debuged the code, and I get the file path not URL, also I have the file in the directory.

Comment: Have you inspected what actually arrives at the client side?

Comment: @mkl I got the document baut Icouldn't display it.

Comment: Have you inspected *the contents* of what actually arrives at the client side? BTW, I just see your code line `resp.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");` - **Don't ever add charset information when transmitting binary data** (and PDFs are binaries) because this may make software try to translate between chrsets.